# Eclipse: I can't get project dependencies into Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am modernizing a project that's been built using Eclipse Kepler's Export control for a few years.  I ran into issues trying to jump straight to my end configuration (Java 8, Tomcat 8, CXF, and using Maven for builds) so I'm trying to do it piecemeal, and I've been stuck for two days.

I am using Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

For historical reasons, I have two projects, MyImpl project with all of the business logic (which is also the client/consumer of a remote web service, hence the CXF), and MyWebApp, a struts 1 dynamic web project.  Everything was good running in Java 7/Tomcat 7.  I am trying to introduce Maven, first into the MyImpl project, then into MyWebApp project, and finally building the web service client code.

I rearranged the source code to the maven way (/src/main/java, /src/test/java, etc.) Then I added a POM.xml with all my dependencies for MyImpl project.  MyImpl project builds just fine, and MyWebApp project references MyImpl project in Eclipse, so that is good, too.  Everything builds, no red Xs.  Our test cases are, ahem, not well developed at this point in time, so I can't run those.

When I try and run on Tomcat 7 inside Eclipse, the Servers tab shows MyWebApp project under the Tomcat 7 server, but it does not show MyImpl project under MyWebApp project, as it did before.  Yes, Java Build Path/Projects shows that MyWebApp project depends on MyImpl project.  Otherwise it wouldn't build.

Tomcat fails to start up with a NoClassDefFoundError:

```
Jun 08, 2016 4:48:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebStarWebApp]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyWebApp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/mygroup/myproject/common/util/DB_Exception
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
...
```

DB_Exception is defined in the MyImpl project.

If I double-click the server, click on "Open launch configuration", click on the Classpath tab, I see the JRE System Library under Bootstrap Entries, and bootstrap.jar, tomcat-juli.jar, and tools.jar under User Entries.  If I add MyWebApp project to User Entries and start the server, I get a class loader exception:

```
Jun 08, 2016 5:20:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "mycompany/common/logging/ISmLog"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
<stack trace through initialization code>
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1158)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If, instead of adding MyWebApp project to the run configuration, I only add MyImpl.jar (digging into the MyImpl project, selecting MyImpl\target\MyImpl-1.0.jar), I still get a NoClassDefFoundError:

```
Jun 08, 2016 5:32:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mycompany/myproject/logging/InstrRecord
    at com.mycompany.myproject.struts.plugins.MyImpl_PlugIn.init(MyImpl_PlugIn.java:55)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:1158)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:473)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mycompany/myproject/logging/InstrRecord
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
```

This is with a brand new workspace and a fresh import of the code base.

Comment: When introducing Maven to your projects, did you remember to introduce the m2e and m2e-wtp plug-ins to Eclipse?

Comment: You need to enable your MyImpl.jar in **Order And Export** tab in Project Properties->Java Build Path

Comment: I have m2e and m2e-wtp installed... 6 lines show up in Help/Installation Details/Features: Eclipse.org - m2e m2e logback configuration, Eclipse.org - m2e Maven Integration for Eclipse, Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP, Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp Maven JAX-RS Configurator, Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp Maven JPA Configurator, and Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp Maven JSF Configuration.

Comment: MyImpl project build path, Order and Export tab, shows both MyImpl/src/test/java and MyImpl/src/main/java checked.  Underneath those, it shows Maven Dependencies, JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7], and Apache CXF Library [2.7.15] are unchecked.  The Libraries tab just shows expandable entries for Apache CXF Library [2.7.15], JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7], and Maven Dependencies.

Comment: MyWebApp project build path, Projects tab, shows MyImpl project, with details Access rules: No rules defined, and Native library location: (None).

Comment: MyWebApp project build path, Libraries tab, shows Apache Tomcat v7.0, JRE System Library, org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.core.CXF_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER/Apache CXF/2.5.4, and Web App Libraries (which has a long list of home grown and 3rd party jars, but does not contain MyImpl.jar).

Comment: MyWebApp project build path, Order and Export tab, has MyWebApp/src/main/java (checked), MyImpl (checked), and Web App Libraries (checked), along with org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.core.CXF_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER/Apache CXF/2.5.4 (unchecked), Apache Tomcat v7.0 [Apache Tomcat v7.0] (unchecked), and finally JRE System LIbrary [jdk1.7.0_79] (unchecked).

Comment: I am going to look into the CXF version discrepency: 2.5.4 (listed) vs. 2.7.15 (installed runtime).  Thank you @Sangram

Comment: I think I fixed this:right click on MyWebApp project, choose Properties.  Click the "Deployment Assembly" property.  On that screen, it let me know that the path to MyImpl was broken; I deleted it, clicked "Add" and then "Archives from Workspace" and navigated to it, clicked "Apply", waited for it to rebuild, removed the MyImpl.jar from the server launch configuration, and now I'm back in business!